# I like the music in/from/of movie

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one of *in*, *from* and *of* should I use to say *I like the music [in/from/of] movie*, if the music is

1. Already known, such as Beethoven's *Moonlight Sonata*?
2. Original (made for the movie)?

Or are there other distinctions that entail with the use of each word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prepositions are hard to teach, especially if the context is limited to one sentence. But all three prepositions could be used. And it does not matter if the movie has original music and/or pre-existing music; the general uses of the prepositions are the same.

1) I like the music **in** the movie *Ray.*

I like the music **featured in, found in, contained in, heard in, played in, etc.** the movie *Ray.*

2) I like the music **from** the movie *Ray.* That is why I bought the OMPST (official motion picture soundtrack) on CD. I can listen to music **from** the movie whenever I want.

So *music **from** the movie* means *the music that **comes from** the movie.*

3) I like the music **of** the movie *Ray.*

This is a general statement. It is like saying:
I like the movie **Ray's** music. Or: I like the movie's music.

You can also say:

4) I like the music **of** Beethoven (= Beethoven's music) **in** the movie *Ray.*

Or:

5) I like the music **of** Beethoven (= Beethoven's music) **from** the movie *Ray.*

But you would probably not hear the above sentence with two *of's* in it.

You could also say:

6) I like the music **of** movies that have Beethoven's "Moonlight Sonata" [in them](https://www.icheckmovies.com/lists/films+with+beethovens+moonlight+sonata+in+it/marco_n65/).

Or:

7) I like Beethoven's "Moonlight Sonata" in the movie *Ray,* but I don't like any of the other music **in**, **from**, *or* **of** the movie.

Edit: It should be clear that it doesn't matter if the music is "original music" or not.

8) The music **in** / **from** / **of** *Forrest Gump* includes all the songs I used to listen to on the radio.

---

[The music **of** *Pulp Fiction*](https://medium.com/cuepoint/the-music-of-pulp-fiction-8a13a7cdb5a8) also mentions The music **of** *Guardians of the Galaxy.* There's the Blog of Doug Adams, which is called [The Music **of** *The Lord of the Rings* Films](http://www.musicoflotr.com). Or [The music **of** *American Horror Story: Freak Show*](http://blogs.wsj.com/speakeasy/2014/10/09/the-music-of-american-horror-story-freak-show-will-be-a-lot-like-life-on-mars/). [Mobile link](http://m.wsj.com/articles/BL-SEB-83960). Or you can buy *The Music **of** Star Wars* or *The Music **of** Grand Theft Auto* if you search for them.

Comment: I disagree on "of". "I like the music of Beethoven" means "I like the music Beethoven wrote." But movies don't write music so it doesn't sound natural to say "I like the music of the movie *Ray*".

Comment: @David Richerby see edit at end of my answer. I don't under the objection, anyway. The scenery of the movie, The theme of the movie, the cinematography of the movie, the score of the movie, the lesson of the movie, the acting of the movie..., the music of the movie.