# Difference between "in" and "of"

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

Can anyone please tell me what's the difference between **in** and **of** in the following sentences? Are they both correct?

- Lionel Messi is the greatest player **of/in** the Argentina football team.
- John is the best student **in/of** the class.
- The roads **in/of** the USA are wider than those of Russia.

Comment: Related questions about in/of, but not duplicates: [Is it “words in a song,” “words to a song,” or “words of a song”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/154365/9161) / [Difference between being at/of/in someone's service](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/133905/9161) / [When to use “of”, “in” and “at”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4553/9161) / [I like the music in/from/of movie](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37556/9161)

Answer (score 2):

*X of Y* has a lot of meanings.  Some of them are:

- Expresses a "belonging" or "ownership" relationship - Y belongs to X
- Expresses the "component" part of a "component-whole" relationship - X is a part of Y.

*X in Y* has several meanings, but it mostly means.

- X is completely or substantially surrounded by all sides/borders/edges of Y.  This can be "3D" (containers or covers; I'm *in* a box) or "2D" (places or areas; I'm *in* a square I drew on the ground with chalk).

If Y is a large container-like entity, like a country, building, etc. the things that "belong to" it or the things that are a "part of" it may lie within it.

So I can say 1st Street is both a road *of* (because it constitutes part of) and a road *in* (because it's surrounded on all sides by the borders of) my neighboorhood, city, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, **in** and **of** are interchangeable. **Of** relates to being a part *of* something, *in* relates to a group somebody is *in*.

If you think of Argentina, the class and the USA, these are **places**, which also can be interpreted as **entities**, giving a reason why both prepositions can be used.

However, I think that if you use **of** in the first sentence, it will give you the impression that Messi is one of the all-time greats of the Argentina football team, if not the greatest; however, **in** will imply that he is the best in the current Argentina football team.